# Upload Multiple Files in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My JS is on github [here](https://github.com/MagnusMarx/VLC-Media-Web-Player).

The live demo is [here](https://magnusmarx.github.io/VLC-Media-Web-Player/).

I want the HTML Button id='Multiple-Files' to allow the user to upload multiple files, display all the selected files in the console, then play them on after another. [Here's what I have so far.](https://github.com/MagnusMarx/VLC-Media-Web-Player/blob/gh-pages/assets/js/index.js)
Sorry for inline links, didn't know that was an issue here. Snippet isnt a good demonstration of the web app, it's mainly here to show the JS and HTML.

```js
const videoElement = document.getElementById("drop-zone-video");
const audioElement = document.getElementById("drop-zone-audio");
const albumArtElement = document.getElementById('drop-zone-image');
const progressBar = document.querySelector(".barz-inner");
const progressBar2 = document.querySelector(".barz-inner-2");
const volumeRange = document.getElementById('volume-range');
const repeat = document.getElementById('btn-repeat');
const playpause = document.getElementById('btn-play-pause');

let jsmediatags = window.jsmediatags;
let isDragging = false;
let currentlyPlayingElement = null;

progressBar.addEventListener("input", handleInput);

function handleInput() {
    const progress = progressBar.value;
    seekTo(progress);
    progressBar.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".drop-zone-input").forEach((inputElement) => {
    const dropZoneElement = inputElement.closest(".drop-zone");
    const openfile = document.getElementById('Open-File');
    const multiplefiles = document.getElementById('Multiple-Files');

    dropZoneElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        inputElement.click();
    });

    openfile.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        inputElement.click();
    });

    multiplefiles.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        const files = Array.from(inputElement.files);
        inputElement.click();
        handleFiles(files);
    });

    inputElement.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        if (inputElement.files.length) {
            updateThumbnail(dropZoneElement, inputElement.files[0]);
            const file = inputElement.files[0];
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
                displayImage(fileURL);
            } else if (file.type.startsWith("video/")) {
                playVideo(fileURL);
                videoElement.play();
                playpause.innerHTML = '⏸'
                videoElement.style.display = "block";
                audioElement.style.display = "none";
            } else if (file.type.startsWith("audio/")) {
                playAudio(fileURL);
                audioElement.play();
                playpause.innerHTML = '⏸'
                videoElement.style.display = "none";
                audioElement.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    });

    dropZoneElement.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dropZoneElement.classList.add("drop-zone--over");
    });

    ["dragleave", "dragend"].forEach((type) => {
        dropZoneElement.addEventListener(type, (e) => {
            dropZoneElement.classList.remove("drop-zone--over");
        });
    });

    function handleFiles(files) {
        files.forEach((file) => {
            console.log("File:", file);

            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
                displayImage(fileURL);
            } else if (file.type.startsWith("video/")) {
                playVideo(fileURL);
            } else if (file.type.startsWith("audio/")) {
                playAudio(fileURL);
            }
        });
    }

    dropZoneElement.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (e.dataTransfer.files.length) {
            inputElement.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
            updateThumbnail(dropZoneElement, e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
            const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
            if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
                displayImage(file);
            } else if (file.type.startsWith("video/")) {
                playVideo(fileURL);
                videoElement.src = fileURL;
                videoElement.play();
                playpause.innerHTML = '⏸'
                videoElement.style.display = "block";
                audioElement.style.display = "none";
            } else if (file.type.startsWith("audio/")) {
                playAudio(fileURL);
                audioElement.src = fileURL;
                audioElement.play();
                playpause.innerHTML = '⏸'
                videoElement.style.display = "none";
                audioElement.style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        dropZoneElement.classList.remove("drop-zone--over");
    });
});

function updateThumbnail(dropZoneElement, file) {
    let thumbnailElement = dropZoneElement.querySelector(".drop-zone-image");

    function extractAlbumArt(file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {

            jsmediatags.read(file, {
                onSuccess: (tag) => {
                    const {
                        tags
                    } = tag;
                    const {
                        picture
                    } = tags;

                    if (picture) {
                        const base64String = arrayBufferToBase64(picture.data);
                        const imageUrl = `data:${picture.format};base64,${base64String}`;
                        rmv = document.getElementById("vlc-icon");
                        rmv.style.display = "none";
                        displayAlbumArt(imageUrl);
                    } else {
                        rmv = document.getElementById("vlc-icon");
                        rmv.style.display = "none";
                        imageUrl = './assets/img/Audio.svg';
                        displayAlbumArt(imageUrl);
                    }
                },
                onError: (error) => {
                    console.error('Error reading MP3 tags:', error);
                    rmv = document.getElementById("vlc-icon");
                    rmv.style.display = "none";
                    imageUrl = './assets/img/Audio.svg';
                    displayAlbumArt(imageUrl);
                }
            });
        };

        reader.onerror = (error) => {
            console.error('Error reading file:', error);
            displayAlbumArt(null);
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }

    function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
        let binary = '';
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        const len = bytes.byteLength;

        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }

        return window.btoa(binary);
    }

    function displayAlbumArt(imageUrl) {

        if (imageUrl) {
            albumArtElement.src = imageUrl;
            albumArtElement.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            albumArtElement.src = '';
            albumArtElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
            thumbnailElement.src = reader.result;
            thumbnailElement.style.display = "block";
            videoElement.style.display = "none";
            audioElement.style.display = "none";
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else if (file.type.startsWith("audio/")) {
        thumbnailElement.style.display = "none";
        videoElement.style.display = "none";
        audioElement.style.display = "block";
        audioElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        audioElement.play();
        playpause.innerHTML = '⏸'
        extractAlbumArt(file);
    } else {
        thumbnailElement.style.display = "none";
        videoElement.style.display = "none";
        audioElement.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (!thumbnailElement) {
        thumbnailElement = document.createElement("div");
        thumbnailElement.classList.add("drop-zone-thumb");
        rmv = document.getElementById("vlc-icon");
        rmv.style.display = "none";
        dropZoneElement.appendChild(thumbnailElement);
    }

    thumbnailElement.dataset.label = file.name;
}

function displayImage(file) {
    if (currentlyPlayingElement) {
        currentlyPlayingElement.src = "";
        currentlyPlayingElement.style.display = "none";
        currentlyPlayingElement = null;
        progressBar.value = 0;
        playpause.innerHTML = '⏵';
        document.getElementById("time-one").innerHTML = '--:--'
        document.getElementById("time-two").innerHTML = '--:--'
    }

    const thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
    const reader = new FileReader();
    document.getElementById("time-one").innerHTML = '--:--';
    document.getElementById("time-two").innerHTML = '--:--';
    reader.onload = () => {
        progressBar.value = 0;
        progressBar2.style.width = '0%';
        thumbnailElement.src = reader.result;
        thumbnailElement.style.display = "block";
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function playVideo(fileURL) {
    if (currentlyPlayingElement === audioElement) {
        audioElement.src = "";
        playpause.innerHTML = '⏵';
        audioElement.style.display = "none";
        progressBar.value = 0;
    }

    videoElement.src = fileURL;
    videoElement.play();
    playpause.innerHTML = '⏸'
    videoElement.style.display = "block";
    currentlyPlayingElement = videoElement;
}

function playAudio(fileURL) {
    if (currentlyPlayingElement === videoElement) {
        videoElement.src = "";
        playpause.innerHTML = '⏵';
        videoElement.style.display = "none";
        progressBar.value = 0;
    }

    audioElement.src = fileURL;
    audioElement.play();
    playpause.innerHTML = '⏸'
    audioElement.style.display = "block";
    currentlyPlayingElement = audioElement;
}

videoElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
    const currentTime = videoElement.currentTime;
    const formattedTime = formatTime(currentTime);
    let Ctime = document.getElementById("time-one");
    Ctime.innerHTML = formattedTime;
});

audioElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
    const currentTime = audioElement.currentTime;
    const formattedTime = formatTime(currentTime);
    let Ctime = document.getElementById("time-one");
    Ctime.innerHTML = formattedTime;
});

videoElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    const duration = videoElement.duration;
    const formattedDuration = formatTime(duration);
    let Ctime = document.getElementById("time-two");
    Ctime.innerHTML = formattedDuration;
});

audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    const duration = audioElement.duration;
    const formattedDuration = formatTime(duration);
    let Ctime = document.getElementById("time-two");
    Ctime.innerHTML = formattedDuration;
});

function formatTime(time) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
    const formattedMinutes = String(minutes).padStart(2, "0");
    const formattedSeconds = String(seconds).padStart(2, "0");
    return `${formattedMinutes}:${formattedSeconds}`;
}

videoElement.addEventListener("play", () => {
    videoElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateProgressBar);

    function updateProgressBar() {
        const currentTime = videoElement.currentTime;
        const duration = videoElement.duration;
        const progress = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
        progressBar.value = progress;
        progressBar2.style.width = `${progress}%`;
        if (!isDragging) {
            const currentTime = videoElement.currentTime;
            const duration = videoElement.duration;
            const progress = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
            progressBar.value = progress;
        }
    }

});

audioElement.addEventListener("play", () => {
    audioElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateProgressBar);

    function updateProgressBar() {
        const currentTime = audioElement.currentTime;
        const duration = audioElement.duration;
        const progress = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
        progressBar.value = progress;
        progressBar2.style.width = `${progress}%`;
        if (!isDragging) {
            const currentTime = audioElement.currentTime;
            const duration = audioElement.duration;
            const progress = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
            progressBar.value = progress;
            progressBar2.style.width = `${progress}%`;
        }
    }
});

function startDrag() {
    isDragging = true;
}

function handleDrag(e) {
    if (isDragging) {
        const progressBarRect = progressBar.getBoundingClientRect();
        const progressWidth = e.clientX - progressBarRect.left;
        const progressBarWidth = progressBarRect.width;
        const progress = (progressWidth / progressBarWidth) * 100;
        progressBar.value = progress;
        seekTo(progress);
    }
}

function endDrag() {
    if (isDragging) {
        isDragging = false;
    }
}

function seekTo(progress) {
    const duration = currentlyPlayingElement.duration;
    if (!isNaN(duration) && isFinite(duration)) {
        const currentTime = (progress / 100) * duration;
        currentlyPlayingElement.currentTime = currentTime;
    }
}

progressBar.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);
progressBar.addEventListener("mousemove", handleDrag);
progressBar.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrag);

let rewindInterval;
let isRewinding = false;
let isSeeking = false;
let playbackRate = 1;
let isRepeating = false;

function Vskipbackward() {
    if (!isRewinding) {
        clearInterval(rewindInterval);
        isRewinding = true;
        playbackRate = 2;
        currentlyPlayingElement.playbackRate = playbackRate;
        currentlyPlayingElement.play();
        rewindInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (currentlyPlayingElement.currentTime <= 0) {
                currentlyPlayingElement.pause();
                isRewinding = false;
                clearInterval(rewindInterval);
            } else {
                currentlyPlayingElement.currentTime -= 2;
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}

function Vskipforward() {
    if (!isSeeking) {
        isSeeking = true;
        playbackRate = 2;
        currentlyPlayingElement.playbackRate = playbackRate;
        currentlyPlayingElement.play();
        seekInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (currentlyPlayingElement.currentTime <= 0) {
                currentlyPlayingElement.pause();
            } else {
                currentlyPlayingElement.currentTime += 2;
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}

function Vtoggle() {
    if (isSeeking) {
        clearInterval(seekInterval);
        isSeeking = false;
        currentlyPlayingElement.playbackRate = 1;
        currentlyPlayingElement.pause();
        currentlyPlayingElement.play();
    } else if (isRewinding) {
        clearInterval(rewindInterval);
        isRewinding = false;
        currentlyPlayingElement.playbackRate = 1;
        currentlyPlayingElement.pause();
        currentlyPlayingElement.play();
    } else if (currentlyPlayingElement.paused) {
        currentlyPlayingElement.play();
        playpause.innerHTML = '⏸'
    } else {
        currentlyPlayingElement.pause();
        playpause.innerHTML = '⏵';
    }
}

function Vstop() {
    if (currentlyPlayingElement) {
        currentlyPlayingElement.src = "";
        currentlyPlayingElement.style.display = "none";
        currentlyPlayingElement = null;
        progressBar.value = 0.01;
        document.getElementById("time-one").innerHTML = '--:--'
        document.getElementById("time-two").innerHTML = '--:--'
        Vstop();
        playpause.innerHTML = '⏵';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("time-one").innerHTML = '--:--';
        document.getElementById("time-two").innerHTML = '--:--';
        playpause.innerHTML = '⏵';
    }
}

function Vfullscreen() {
    const docElement = document.documentElement;

    if (
        !document.fullscreenElement &&
        !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
        !document.webkitFullscreenElement &&
        !document.msFullscreenElement
    ) {

        if (docElement.requestFullscreen) {
            docElement.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (docElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            docElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (docElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            docElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (docElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
            docElement.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    } else {

        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}

function toggleRepeat() {
    isRepeating = !isRepeating;
    if (isRepeating) {
        repeat.classList.toggle('repeat-active');
        currentlyPlayingElement.loop = true;
    } else {
        repeat.classList.toggle('repeat-active');
        currentlyPlayingElement.loop = false;
    }
}

volumeRange.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const volume = volumeRange.value / 100;
    videoElement.volume = volume;
    audioElement.volume = volume;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://magnusmarx.github.io/VLC-Media-Web-Player/assets/css/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/img/VLC.svg">
    <title>VLC Media Player</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="VLC-body">
        <div class="nav">
            <a class="media">Media</a>
            <div class="menu" id="media">
                <a id="Open-File">Open File</a>
                <a id="Multiple-Files">Open Multiple Files</a>
                <a>Open Folder</a>
                <a class="inactive">Open Disc</a>
                <a>Open Network Stream</a>
                <a>Open Capture Card</a>
                <a>Open Location from Clipboard</a>
                <a>Open Recent Media</a>
                <a>Save Playlist to File</a>
                <a>Convert / Save</a>
                <a>Stream</a>
                <a>Quit at the end of Playlist</a>
                <a>Quit</a>
            </div>
            <a class="playback">Playback</a>
            <div class="menu" id="playback">
                <a>Title</a>
                <a>Chapter</a>
                <a>Program</a>
                <a>Custom Bookmarks</a>
                <a>Renderer</a>
                <a>Speed</a>
                <a>Jump Forward</a>
                <a>Jump Backward</a>
                <a>Jump to Specific Time</a>
                <a>Play</a>
                <a>Stop</a>
                <a>Previous</a>
                <a>Next</a>
                <a>Record</a>
            </div>
            <a class="audio">Audio</a>
            <div class="menu" id="audio">
                <a>Audio Track</a>
                <a>Audio Device</a>
                <a>Stereo Mode</a>
                <a>Visualization</a>
                <a>Increase Volume</a>
                <a>Decrease Volume</a>
                <a>Mute</a>
            </div>
            <a class="video">Video</a>
            <div class="menu" id="video">
                <a>Video Track</a>
                <a>Fullscreen</a>
                <a>Always Fit to Window</a>
                <a>Set as Wallpaper</a>
                <a>Zoom</a>
                <a>Aspect Ratio</a>
                <a>Crop</a>
                <a>Deinterlace</a>
                <a>Deinterlace Mode</a>
                <a>Take Snapshot</a>
            </div>
            <a class="subtitle">Subtitle</a>
            <div class="menu" id="subtitle">
                <a>Add Subtitle File</a>
                <a>Sub Track</a>
            </div>
            <a class="tools">Tools</a>
            <div class="menu" id="tools">
                <a>Effects & Filters</a>
                <a>Track Synchronization</a>
                <a>Media Information</a>
                <a>Codec Information</a>
                <a>VLM Configuration</a>
                <a>Program Guide</a>
                <a>Messages</a>
                <a>Plugins & Extensions</a>
                <a>Customize Interface</a>
                <a>Preferences</a>
            </div>
            <a class="view">View</a>
            <div class="menu" id="view">
                <a>Playlist</a>
                <a>Docked Playlist</a>
                <a>Playlist View Mode</a>
                <a>Always On Top</a>
                <a>Minimal Interface</a>
                <a>Fullscreen Interface</a>
                <a>Advanced Controls</a>
                <a>Status Bar</a>
                <a>Add Interface</a>
                <a>VLsUb</a>
            </div>
            <a class="help">Help</a>
            <div class="menu" id="help">
                <a>Help</a>
                <a>Check for Updates...</a>
                <a>About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-zone">
            <img class="vlc-icon" id="vlc-icon" src="./assets/img/VLC.svg">
            <input type="file" name="the-file" class="drop-zone-input" accept="image/*, audio/*, video/*">
            <video class="drop-zone-video" id="drop-zone-video"></video>
            <audio class="drop-zone-audio" id="drop-zone-audio"></audio>
            <img class="drop-zone-image" id="drop-zone-image">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-bar">
            <div class="progress-bar">
                <span class="time-one" id="time-one">--:--</span>
                <span class="time-two" id="time-two">--:--</span>
                <div class="progress-barz">
                    <input type="range" step="0.01" value="0.01" class="barz-inner">
                    <div class="barz-inner-2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-bar">
                <button class="btn-play-pause" id="btn-play-pause" onclick="Vtoggle()">⏵</button>
                <button class="btn-skip-backward" id="btn-skip-backward" onclick="Vskipbackward()">⏮</button>
                <button class="btn-stop" id="btn-stop" onclick="Vstop()">⏹</button>
                <button class="btn-skip-forward" id="btn-skip-forward" onclick="Vskipforward()">⏭</button>
                <button class="btn-fullscreen" id="btn-fullscreen" onclick="Vfullscreen()">⛶</button>
                <button class="btn-eq" id="btn-eq" title="Coming Soon!" onclick="null"></button>
                <button class="btn-playlist" id="btn-playlist" title="Coming Soon!" onclick="null">≡</button>
                <button class="btn-repeat" id="btn-repeat" onclick="toggleRepeat()">⥀</button>
                <button class="btn-shuffle" id="btn-shuffle" title="Coming Soon!" onclick="null">⤨</button>
                <div class="volume-slider">
                    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" class="slider" id="volume-range">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="./assets/js/jsmediatags.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./assets/js/index.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: "I want the HTML Button id='Multiple-Files' to allow the user to upload multiple files, display all the selected files in the console, then play them on after another." — What *specific* problem are you having?

Comment: I want to be able to display the multiple selected files in the js console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#additional_attributes

Use the file input field with the multiple attribute.

```
<input type="file" id="multi-file" name="filefield" multiple="multiple">
```

If you want it to look like a button you'll need to do some css magic or visually hide the file input and have it's file selection prompt trigger by the button, some thing like (disclaimer: untested, just a gist):

```
document.getElementById("multi-file-button").addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById("multi-file").click()
})
```